# PDI - PosgreSQL Bulk Load error, Insert/Update and Table Output slow

Tags: kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

i wanna ask about this :
BTW, I'm new with PostgreSQL and PDI.
I have search about this in internet and I don't get it how PostgresSQL Bulk Load work and why this error (image below) show up.

[PostgreSQL Bulk Load Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkMQW.jpg)

This error show up when I try to insert CSV into postgres DB.

Why I used PostgreSQL Bulk Load? 'cause in my transformation after doing some ETL to my data and try to insert it directly using `Table Output or Insert/Update` into postgre DB it take long time (17m rows take 2h55m with speed 1.500-1.750 rows/s). And I will have about 75m+ rows of data that need to process. 

That why I use PostgreSQL Bulk Load and change my transformation.
I will have 2 tranformations. 1 for data process and another one for insert using bulk load.
1st transformation, `Text File Input` > do some ETL and process the data > `Text Files Output` as CSV again.
2st transformation is like the image above.
Or if you guys have any idea/another way to do it please?

Comment: which version of PDI?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin 8.0

Answer (score 0):

you can try by using below fix of PostgreSQL Bulk Loader

https://github.com/dexalex84/PentahoKettlePostgreSQLBulkInsertFix/blob/master/engine/src/org/pentaho/di/trans/steps/pgbulkloader/PGBulkLoader.java

Comment: what should I do with that java code? is this a proper way to solve my problem? can u explain it to me? like I said I'm new with these thing

Comment: you need to build that code and make jar file use it inside plugins folder

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin can you explain how to use it, and where to put it? i have same issue as the author